# Java - type inference for array paramater of a generic method

Tags: java, arrays, generics, type-inference, generic-method

Type inference doesn't seem to work for arrays with generic methods? I receive the error 'The method contains(T[], T) is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int)'. How should I be doing this?

```
method(new int[1], 0); //Error

...

public static <T> void method(T[] array, T value) {
    //Implement
}
```

Comment: Generics doesn't work with primitive types, it's for objects only. Try with `new Integer[1], 0` instead.

Comment: It's also a reason why `Double`, `Integer`, `Boolean`,... is created in Java.

Comment: What do you mean when you say primitives don't work with generic types? int works just fine, it's just the array which is causing issues

Comment: By the way, in this case, the generics is useless. It would be identical if declared as `public static void method(Object[] array, Object value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics doesn't work with primitive types, only with object types.

You can do what looks like using generics with primitive types, due to auto-boxing:

```
<T> void methodOne(T value) {}

methodOne(1);  // Compiles OK, T = Integer.
```

What is actually happening here is that the `int` literal `1` is being "boxed" to `Integer.valueOf(1)`, which is an object of type `Integer`.

You can pass also an `int[]` to a generic method, because `int[]` is an object type itself. So:

```
methodOne(new int[1]);  // Compiles OK, T = int[].
```

However, you can't mix these two with the same type variable: `int[]` and `Integer` are not related types, so there is no single type variable `T` which is satisfied by both parameters. There is no equivalent auto-boxing operator from `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

As such, you would need to pass an `Integer[]` array as the first parameter:

```
method(new Integer[1], 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Integer instead of int, since generics don't work with primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

why use `primitive` type here. Generics only work with `referenced` type.

```
method(new int[1], 0); //Error
```

better to go with

```
 method(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4}, 0); //works fine
```